# How to interpret interaction plots of generalized additive models?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I am seeking assistance in interpreting the interaction plots of a generalized additive model (GAM). I wish to know:

1. What does the `linear predictor` on $y$ axis mean?
2. What does the arrows along $x_1$ and $x_2$ indicate?
3. Is the interaction negative or positive? How to interpret positive or negative
   interaction in plots?

Here is my model:

```
mod1 <-
  gam(
    y ~  te(x1,  x2, k = 4) +  te(x1, x2, k = 5),
    family = betar(),
    method = "REML",
    data = dat
  )

summary(mod1)



Family: Beta regression(8.84) 
Link function: logit 

Formula:
  y ~ te(x1, x2, k = 4) + 
  te(x3, x4, k = 5)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -0.03709    0.12465  -0.298    0.766

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
          edf     Ref.df Chi.sq p-value    
te(x1, x2) 3.000   3.00  39.62  <2e-16 ***
te(x3, x4) 6.608   6.93  78.30  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.667   Deviance explained = 90.9%
-REML = -45.944  Scale est. = 1         n = 50
```

Here is the code to produce the plots:

```
vis.gam(mod1, view = c("x1",  "x2"), theta = 120, plot.type = "persp")
vis.gam(mod1, view = c("x3",  "x4"), theta = 120, plot. Type = "persp")
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is this homework? The particular form of the model and plots looks set up somewhat precisely for a specific  pedagogical purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A video that may be helpful for understanding these plots can be found [here,](https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/nonlinear-modeling-with-generalized-additive-models-gams-in-r/spatial-gams-and-interactions?ex=4) where Noam Ross explains them to a degree. The interaction plot shown is essentially a topographic "map" of the tensor product interaction which shows how the response varies as a function of the two predictors in your model. In terms of what this means for your questions...

> 1. What does the `linear predictor` on $y$ axis mean?

The linear predictor is actually summarized in [Wood's book on GAMs](https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/mono/10.1201/9781315370279/generalized-additive-models-simon-wood) as follows:

> Linear models are statistical models in which a univariate response is modelled as the sum of a ‘linear predictor’ and a zero mean random error term. **The linear predictor depends on some predictor variables, measured with the response variable, and some unknown parameters, which must be estimated.** A key feature of the models is that the linear predictor depends linearly on the parameters.

Another way of saying it is that a linear predictor is a linear *function* (linear combination) of a set of coefficients and explanatory variables (independent variables), whose value is used to predict the outcome of a dependent variable.

In terms of what that means for your plots, you can just consider this the predicted outcome in your model, which is based off your predictor terms. As the predicted outcome increases (arrow pointing upwards on the plot), this generally turns the topological map "more yellow", while decreases in the predicted outcome turn the map "more red." What this means in terms of your interaction is detailed further below in my answer.

> 2. What does the arrows along $x_1$ and $x_2$ indicate?

They indicate how high or low the value is. For example, when $x_1$ is at the end of the arrow (where it is "pointy"), this is it's maximum value. The opposite end is it's minimum value.

> 3. Is the interaction negative or positive? How to interpret positive or negative
>    interaction in plots?

The interaction depends on where one is looking. Since the interaction here is nonlinear, it shifts based on location. It is hard to see in your particular case (sometimes these are better visualized in 2D contour plots instead), but the yellow regions are where the interaction is positive (when the interaction has a more positive influence on the outcome) and the red regions are when the interaction is negative (when the interaction has a more negative influence on the outcome).

One final note...here you have estimated a tensor product  <s>interaction</s>  smooth between two variables using the `te()` function. This includes the estimated relationship between both variables, but does not include the independent main effects of each variable *separately*. To achieve that, one would need to use the `ti()` function instead, but that depends on your purpose here. See the details about each at [this link.](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/mgcv/html/smooth.terms.html)

Comment: Your last paragraph is wrong. It is the other way around: `te` is a full tensor product smoother, `ti` is a tensor product interaction smoother.

Comment: I am aware of that distinction and I don't believe in principal it is markedly different from what I wrote, but I realize my wording is perhaps poor there. To clarify with more specificity I have included some different wording and the link for the functions in hopes my answer is more clear.